# Is there a way not to let MsBuild run static contract analysis with code contracts?

Tags: msbuild, code-contracts

In my project, static checking is disabled, but still, when I run msbuild.exe with cmd, it starts static checking for each project... Is there a way, with parameters, to disable this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might be a 'little' late, but since I just encountered the same problem and `/p:RunCodeAnalysis=false` doesn't work for me:

Try `msbuild ... /p:CodeContractsRunCodeAnalysis=false`.

That works as of Feb. 2011 according to [the code contracts documentation](http://download.microsoft.com/download/c/2/7/c2715f76-f56c-4d37-9231-ef8076b7ec13/userdoc.pdf) and my experience.

Answer (score 2):

The following should do it:

```
MSBuild ... /p:RunCodeAnalysis=false
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to pass parameters to msbuild or you are building from Visual Studio, there is a way to suppress static code contracts check and code analysis.

Notice: each *.csproj file contains this: `<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />`.

For .Net 4.0 msbuild.exe and `Microsoft.CSharp.targets` path is `"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\"`

Open `Microsoft.CSharp.targets`
Add new `PropertyGroup` inside `Project` like:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
...
 <PropertyGroup>  
   <CodeContractsRunCodeAnalysis>false</CodeContractsRunCodeAnalysis>
   <RunCodeAnalysis>Never</RunCodeAnalysis>
   <CodeContractsReferenceAssembly>DoNotBuild</CodeContractsReferenceAssembly>
 </PropertyGroup>
...
<!-- a lot of stuff -->
...
</Project>
```

Doing so will emulate msbuild command line arguments (i.e `/p:CodeContractsRunCodeAnalysis=false,RunCodeAnalysis=Never,CodeContractsReferenceAssembly=DoNotBuild`

All your builds now on your pc (either from MSBuild and Visual Studio) will skip code and static code contracts analysis, so you don't need to pass args from Command Line.